# useState re-renders the component(on a button click). I need to change the background of the component to red for 1 second before this happens

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, async-await, hook, settimeout

I need to display the background as red only for a second once the user clicks on the button that updates the state. Once the state is updated the displayed values change. So before this happens I need to change the background to a particular color(green/red/blue) before the state changes but only for a second. I tried using setTimeOut() but might not be using it correctly

```
 const [rightOptionBgColor1, setRightOptionBgColor1] = useState('#95d4ed');
```

```
async function onPressOptionRight1()  {       
        setRightOptionBgColor1('green');
      
        
    };
```

```
   <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onPressOptionRight1}>
                        <View style={[styles.twoOptions,  { backgroundColor: rightOptionBgColor1 }]}>
                        
                            <Text style={styles.textStyles} >{rightAns}</Text>
                           
                        </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

## **-------Edited Updated Answer----------**

I have created a working snack of what you want to achieve but before viewing it read the answer below. here's snack link

https://snack.expo.dev/@crystalarcus/usestate-with-timeout

You can easily achieve it with `useEffect` hook.
`useEffect` can be used to do something after the specific `useState`  changes.

`useEffect` takes 2 arguments, first the `function` be executed every time state change, second a `array` of variables ( useState ).
Syntax is simple : `useEffect( function , [array of varaibles])`

```
useEffect( 
    ()=>{
       //function to be executed
    } ,  
    [var1, var2]   // array of variables
);
```

Everytime variables in `array` change, `useEffect` executes `function` passed into it.

Instead of `TouchableWithoutFeedback`, I suggest you use `Pressable` component.

NOTE : ALWAYS USE `useEffect` right above return statement of component and below other `useState` variables.

So This is how you use it:

```
export default function App() {

    // All the useStates here -------
    const [color, setColor] = useState('#eee');
    const [textColor, setTextColor] = useState('#000');
    const [isAnswered, setIsAnswered] = useState(false);

    const onPressed = () => {
      setColor(value); // set button color
      setIsAnswered(true); // setIsAnswered true so useEffect is triggered
    }

    useEffect(() => {     // <---- use it here 
      if (isAnswered) {
        setTimeout(() => { 
          alert('Answer was clicked'); // function which you want to execute
        }, 2000);  // Time after which you want to execute funtion
      }
    }, [isAnswered])

    return (   // <------ return statement of component
      <View>
        <Pressable onPress={onPressed}>
           // Components Inside button 
       </Pressable>
      </View>
   )
}
```

Explanation :

As you see, useState `isAnswered` is passed in `useEffect` at the end. This means the function passed to it will be triggered everytime `isAnswered` changes. `setTimeout` have been used to wait and function passed inside it will be executed after timeout.

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Even if I use Pressable, while the useState is called the whole component gets re-rendered.

Comment: @gopalprabhu can I know why you want to change color before state is updated ? Like normally, UI designing principles suggest to change buttons color only when pressing/hovering mouse/focused. What do you want to achieve here exactly ?
Also is your Button a separate functional component or is it directly in code ?

Comment: use case: User clicks on the button, then it changes the color before the next question renders so that the user would be able to understand whether they selected the right option.

Comment: @gopalprabhu I have found a way to achieve what u want, I will update answer in an hour, make sure to check out

Comment: @gopalprabhu I have Updated answer and also created working snack and link is in the answer. Hope this will help